Constant recompositions during animation
I am facing a bug. While the user scrolls the lazy list, the ServerSelectionTopBar should be animated. Animation works just fine, but when animation goes, the ServerSelectionTopBar gets constantly recomposed.
@Composable
fun ServerSelectionScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navController: NavHostController,
    viewModel: ServerSelectionViewModel,
) {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    val scrollOffset = calculateScrollOffset(listState, 100)

    val servers by viewModel.filteredServers.collectAsState()
    val isRefreshing by viewModel.isRefreshing.collectAsState()
    val error by viewModel.error.collectAsState()
    val selectedServerId by viewModel.selectedServerId.collectAsState()
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        viewModel.navigationEvents.collect { event ->
            when (event) {
                is ServerSelectionNavigationEvent.ShowPaywall -> {
                    navController.navigate(SUBSCRIPTION_SCREEN)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Scaffold(
        containerColor = Color(0xff071326),
        topBar = {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .statusBarsPadding()
                    .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp, top = 8.dp),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                ClickableIcon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.chevron_left),
                    contentDescription = "Back",
                    tint = Color(0xff2694ff),
                    onClick = { navController.popBackStack() },
                    interactionSource = interactionSource
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                ClickableText(
                    text = stringResource(id = R.string.back_top_bar),
                    onClick = { navController.popBackStack() },
                    interactionSource = interactionSource
                )
            }
            Column {
                ServerSelectionTopBar(
                    listState = listState,
                    scrollOffset = scrollOffset,
                    onBackClick = {
                        navController.popBackStack()
                    },
                    onSearchQueryChanged = viewModel::onSearchQueryChanged
                )
            }
        }
    ) { paddingValues ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(paddingValues)
        ) {
            SwipeRefresh(
                state = rememberSwipeRefreshState(isRefreshing),
                onRefresh = { viewModel.refreshServers() },
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                Column(
                    modifier = modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp)
                ) {
                    when {
                        error.isNotEmpty() -> Text(
                            text = error,
                            color = Color.Red,
                            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                        )

                        else -> ServerSelectionContent(
                            listState = listState,
                            servers = servers,
                            selectedServerId = selectedServerId,
                            onSelectServer = { server ->
                                viewModel.selectServer(server)
                                if (!server.premium) {
                                    navController.popBackStack()
                                }
                            },
                            getPingDisplay = viewModel::getPingDisplay,
                            onShowPaywall = {
                                navController.navigate(SUBSCRIPTION_SCREEN)
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ServerSelectionContent(
    listState: LazyListState,
    servers: List<Server>,
    selectedServerId: Int?,
    onSelectServer: (Server) -> Unit,
    onShowPaywall: () -> Unit,
    getPingDisplay: (Int?) -> Pair<String, Color>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    LazyColumn(
        state = listState,
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(bottom = 24.dp)
    ) {
        items(servers, key = { it.id }) { server ->
            val (pingText, pingColor) = getPingDisplay(server.ping)
            ServerCardItem(
                server = server,
                isSelected = server.id == selectedServerId,
                onSelectServer = onSelectServer,
                pingText = pingText,
                pingColor = pingColor
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ServerCardItem(
    server: Server,
    isSelected: Boolean,
    onSelectServer: (Server) -> Unit,
    pingText: String,
    pingColor: Color,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    val checkedState = rememberUpdatedState(newValue = isSelected)
    val countryName = server.country.name
    val cityName = server.location
    val image = server.icon

    CustomCard(
        onClick = {
            onSelectServer(server)
        },
        frontElement = {
            CustomCheckCircle(
                isChecked = checkedState.value,
                onValueChange = {
                    onSelectServer(server)
                },
                checkedColor = Color(0xff2694ff),
                uncheckedColor = Color.Transparent,
                colorBorder = Color(0xff888d97),
                iconColor = Color.White,
                size = 24f,
            )
        },
        midElement = {
            AsyncImage(
                model = image,
                contentDescription = "Server icon",
                modifier = modifier
                    .size(32.dp)
                    .clip(CircleShape),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
            )
            Column(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(2.dp, Alignment.Top)
            ) {
                Row(
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp, Alignment.Start),
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = countryName,
                        color = Color.White,
                        style = Typography.labelLarge
                    )
                    if (server.premium) {
                        Image(
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.gem_icon),
                            contentDescription = "star",
                            modifier = modifier.requiredSize(size = 18.dp)
                        )
                    }
                }
                Text(
                    text = server.name,
                    color = Color.White.copy(alpha = 0.5f),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    style = Typography.bodySmall
                )
            }
        },
        endElement = {
            Row(
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp, Alignment.Start)
            ) {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.signal_bars),
                    contentDescription = "bars",
                    modifier = modifier.requiredSize(size = 16.dp),
                    colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(pingColor)
                )
                Text(
                    text = pingText,
                    color = Color.White.copy(alpha = 0.5f),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.End,
                    style = Typography.bodySmall,
                    modifier = modifier.wrapContentHeight(align = Alignment.CenterVertically)
                )
            }
        },
        containerColor = Color.White.copy(alpha = 0.04f)
    )
}

// Function to calculate scroll offset
@Composable
fun calculateScrollOffset(
    listState: LazyListState,
    maxScrollOffset: Int,
): androidx.compose.runtime.State<Int> {
    return remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            (listState.firstVisibleItemIndex * listState.layoutInfo.viewportSize.height +
                    listState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset).coerceIn(0, maxScrollOffset)
        }
    }
}

// Updated ServerSelectionTopBar composable
@Composable
fun ServerSelectionTopBar(
    listState: LazyListState,
    scrollOffset: androidx.compose.runtime.State<Int>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onBackClick: () -> Unit,
    onSearchQueryChanged: (String) -> Unit,
) {
    val maxScrollOffset = 100
    val screenWidthDp = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

    // Animate the height
    val animatedHeight by animateDpAsState(targetValue = 180.dp - (40.dp * (scrollOffset.value / maxScrollOffset.toFloat())))

    // Animate the font size
    val animatedFontSize by animateFloatAsState(targetValue = 24f - (8f * (scrollOffset.value / maxScrollOffset.toFloat())))

    // Animate the translation Y
    val animatedTranslationY by animateFloatAsState(targetValue = 170f - (80f * (scrollOffset.value / maxScrollOffset.toFloat())))

    // Animate the translation X
    val animatedTranslationX by animateFloatAsState(targetValue = with(density) {
        0f + ((screenWidthDp / 2 - 52).dp.toPx() * (scrollOffset.value / maxScrollOffset.toFloat()))
    })

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(animatedHeight)
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .graphicsLayer {
                        translationX = animatedTranslationX
                        translationY = animatedTranslationY
                    }
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(R.string.servers),
                    color = Color.White,
                    style = TextStyle(
                        fontSize = animatedFontSize.sp,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                    ),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(top = 8.dp, bottom = 24.dp)
                )
            }
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .graphicsLayer {
                        translationY = animatedTranslationY
                    }
            ) {
                SearchBar(
                    hint = stringResource(R.string.search),
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    onTextChange = onSearchQueryChanged
                )
            }
        }
    }
}



I have tried using derivedStateOf() but it didn't help me. Tried isolating animations, also no effect.
I thought that maybe rememberLazyListState() is somehow updates the scroll state, which can cause recomposition, but haven't found any useful documentation on my case

Have you tried adding logs to check if calculateScrollOffset method is called repeatedly?

@AkshayBhat'AB' Yes, I tried. calculateScrollOffset is called every time the user scrolls. However, when the user scrolls far down, once the animation stops, despite calculateScrollOffset calls, recompositions do not happen.

So you mean ServerSelectionTopBar gets constantly recomposed even if the scroll has stopped?

@AkshayBhat'AB' No. Recomposition happens until the scroll offset does not reach 100 (max set value). Before reaching 100, on every new value in scroll offset recomposition happens.

Since you are animating the height using animatedHeight, your ServerSelectionTopBar composable is recomposed. I don't see an issue here.

@AkshayBhat'AB' but during the animation nothing changes except of the height of an element. As I remember, we can jump over the recomposition step directly to layout or redraw. The recomposition itself is not a big problem on high-end devices, but on low-end devices it can cause stutters in animation.

@AkshayBhat'AB' Also, the fact that not only is the column itself getting recomposed, but elements text inside a column. Surprisingly, SearchBar() blocks recompositions.

You can try wrapping outer layer with Surface since it is not inline fun. Box, Row, Column are inline fun, so outer elements are recomposed.

@AkshayBhat'AB' Still seeing recompositions even with Surface: https://hatebin.com/tzzbndhiwu
